# Parsehub Selection Node Syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-parsing

I'm trying to use parsehub to extract data from a website. Using the selection tool I am able to isolate the title header of each section but I am unable to deselect the first cell of the second header row using alt-click.  The selection node criteria changes but the actual selection does not.
The block of HTML in question

```
    <tr>
    <td width="100%" align="center">
    <table width="493">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#99cc00" height="17">
    <th height="17" colspan="3" title="Scratcher Name"><div align="center"   class="txt_white_bold">LUCKY 7`S #348</div></th>
  </tr>


<tr bgcolor="#99cc00" height="17">
    <th height="17"><div align="center" class="txt_white_bold">Prize Amount</div></th>
    <th align="right"><div align="center" class="txt_white_bold">Prizes Remaining</div></th>
    <th align="right"><div align="center" class="txt_white_bold">Total Prizes</div></th>
  </tr>
```

The Selection Node code is as follows
Selection 1

```
 {
      "op": "select",
      "tag": "TR",
      "allDescendants": true,
      "flags": [
        {
          "position": 4
        }
      ]
    }
```

Selection 2

```
{
  "op": "select",
  "tag": "TH",
  "position": 1
}
```

Selection 3

```
 {
      "op": "select",
      "tag": "DIV",
      "classes": [
        "txt_white_bold"
      ],
      "position": 1
    }
```

The current output is

```
{
"selection1":[
{
"extract1":"LUCKY 7`S #348"
},
{
"extract1":"Prize Amount"
},
```

etc.. how do I only select "Scratcher Name" and not "Prize Amount"?

My first thought was to change 'Selection 3' to select items within TH that have title="Scratcher Name", but I have not been successful in coding it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParseHub's learning algorithms don't yet take all attributes into account, so in some (fairly rare) cases, it won't do what you expect. In this case, you can always use a css or xpath selector to manually select the elements you want.

To do so:

1. Make any arbitrary selection
2. Click the green edit button in the node details
3. Delete all the textareas that exist except one
4. Replace the json in the remaining textarea with

   `{
    "op": "cssSelect",
    "selector": "th[title='Scratcher Name'] div.txt_white_bold",
    "allDescendants": true
   }`

You can also use xpathSelect if you'd like to use xpath instead.